# Share WHM Mysql Database Between to cpanel

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, whm

i have  WHM Server. where i have multiple c panels and multiple domains.

Cpanel1 is connected to my.domain1.com
Cpanel2 is connected to my.domain2.com
Cpanel3 is connected to my.domain3.com

on Cpanel1 i have a database named **centeralizeDB** that is accessible from WHM and Cpanel1. i can view and edit it from cPanel1.

Now i want to access the same database **centeralizeDB** from Cpanel2 and would be visible on the phpMyAdmin of Cpanel2.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON truecall_centrilize_db.* TO 'cpseuse1'@'65.x.a.b' IDENTIFIED BY ''; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON truecall_centrilize_db.* TO 'cpses_lowo4r231y'@'65.x.31.b' IDENTIFIED BY ''; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

i have use these commmand but this is not working. any other method.

Comment: you can you mysql workbench